# List of macro variables in a keep statement in SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I have variable names stored in macro variables that I want to use in a `keep` statement in a data step.  Below is an example:

```
data mydata;
set oldata;
keep &macrovar1-&macrovar&lastnum;
run;
```

I get an error trying to use the code above, with the problem being the `&macrovar&lastnum`.  `&lastnum` is the total number of variables I want to keep.  If I replace &macrovar&lastnum with &macrovar# I get the error as well.  I can get the code to work if I replace `&macrovar&lastnum` with `&macrovar#` and then list out all of the `&macrovar` variables individually, `&macrovar1 &macrovar2 ... &macrovar#` for example.  Is there a certain syntax necessary to get the code above to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do macro variables in automatic lists like that.

What you probably should be doing is selecting the values into a single macro variable.  Are you doing something like this?

```
proc sql;
 select name into :mvar1-:mvar999
  from dataset;
quit;
```

Do this instead:

```
proc sql;
  select name into :mvarlist separated by ' '
    from dataset;
quit;
```